# aligning a two divs next to each other when one div is nested in tags and the other is outside these tags

Tags: css, html, alignment

As images say more than 1000 words, here's my problem (note: I can't post images because I don't have enough SO reputation, so I'll post a link):

http://s7.directupload.net/images/120604/skhgwuqb.png

Here's the use case:
The black, surrounding div is a page preview. The blue divs inside the black div are sections of this page. The blue divs outside are "edit" buttons. They should have the same vertical position as their correspondants.

because the black div and it's contents are a page preview, I cannot move the edit buttons inside the div (without altering the page template to have "edit" buttons, which of course is bad by design).

How can I align them? If Javascript is necessary to achieve this, it will be okay, although I strongly favor a CSS solution.

Comment: can't you post a picture of desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a CSS-only way to achieve what you want if you can't touch anything in the surrounding div. Here's a jQuery solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/BuS2p/

```
<!doctype html><html><head>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
#surrounding_div {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 position: relative;
 background: blue;
}

#elm1 {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: red;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px; top: 20px;
}

#elm2 {
 float: left;
 width: 350px;
 height: 100px;
 background: green;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 150px;    
}
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="surrounding_div">
  <div id="elm1">Testing</div>
  <div id="elm2">Testing</div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    $('#surrounding_div div').each(function() {
        theDiv = $(this);
        divOffset = theDiv.offset();
        $('<button>Edit</button>').appendTo('body').css({
          'left' : $('#surrounding_div').width() + 20,
          'top' : divOffset.top,
          'position' : 'absolute',
          'z-index' : 9000
        });
    });
});
</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that perfectly does the job.

Comment: So you lied in line "although I strongly favor a CSS solution."

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble: If my English parser is working correctly, I think OP does not want the Edit buttons to be placed inside the surrounding `<div>` element. I am not aware of any CSS-only way that allows positioning elements outside the surrounding `<div>` to have the exact same vertical position of an element inside said `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure css solution

```
<div style="border:solid;width:200px;height:400px;">
<div style="position:relative;width:500px;height:100px;"><div style="position:absolute;"><div style="width:190px;float:left;border:solid #3300FF;height:100px;"></div><div style="margin-left:10px;border:solid #3300FF;height:10px;width:100px;float:left;"></div></div>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;width:500px; height:100px;"><div style="position:absolute;"><div style="width:190px;float:left;border:solid #3300FF;height:100px;"></div><div style="margin-left:10px;border:solid #3300FF;height:10px;width:100px;float:left;"></div></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simply HTML and css

```
<div id="surrounding_div">
    <div id="elm1">Testing <button>Edit</button></div>
    <div id="elm2">Testing
        <button>Edit</button>
    </div></div>

#surrounding_div {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background: blue;
}

#elm1 ,#elm2{position:relative;}

#elm1 button ,#elm2 button{position:absolute; top:-4px; right:-250px}
#elm2 button{right:-50px}


#elm1 {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: red;
}

#elm2 {
float: left;
width: 350px;
height: 100px;
background: green;  
}
```